# Same string comparison never returns true

Tags: javascript

If I assign:

```
Content = 'On'
```

and check

```
if ('On' === Content) {} // it returns true
```

But when I get a value dynamically returned from Content as On. I could see 'On' in `console.log`

```
if ('On' === Content) {}
// this never returns true, they are same case(case sensitiveness) as well.
```

May I know what could be the reason?

Comment: Throw that pipe away! Providing the actual issue code would be a good start ;)

Comment: There are a few tools to inspect strings. E.g., when doing `"On".length`, I expect `2`. When doing `Array.from("On")`, I expect `[ "O", "n" ]`. When doing `Array.from("On", (string) => string.codePointAt())`, I expect `[ 79, 110 ]`. When doing `Array.from("On", (string) => string.codePointAt().toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, "0")).join(" ")`, I expect `"4F 6E"`. Do the same thing for `Content`. Check its type. [Edit] your post and provide a [mre] we can work with. [`trim`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) might help.

Comment: without full code (or at least minimal reproducible example), it's really hard to debug this.  You said that you get Content value dynamically, what do you mean by that? how was `Content` value assigned? i'd guess it's either because race condition or you didn't declare the `Content` variable

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Below answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trim the dynamic content variable like the below and then try:

```
if ('On' === Content.trim()) {}
```